# Exception in a LIKE query with DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

My input is '[CL' i am missing closing bracket. And columns contain '[CL]'. I am using like query to fine in Column 'MYStps'. But i am getting an exception. Below Image is attached.

```
{
    DataRow[] searchResult = MyDataTable.Select("MYStps Like '%" + txtSearchLog_Level.Text.Trim() + "%'");
}
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: You have to provide more detailed code. For example what is this: txtSearchLog_Level? Obviously you are outputting "[CL"

Comment: @ohlmar OP says textbox has `[CL`

Comment: What about Linq solution? `var searchResult = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("MYStps").Contains(txtSearchLog_Level.Text.Trim())).ToArray()`

Comment: the problem is in '[' character. when you are trying to filter record using '[' character then visual studio will throws an exception "Error in Like Operator. use [[] instead of [. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac6a68c0-c254-4e73-8b72-7886f92c06d8/special-charecters-in-the-filter-expression-for-datatableselectfilterexpression?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

Because your text contains `[` and it is a [*wildcard character*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#Databases).

From [`LIKE (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) under the section "Using Wildcard Characters As Literals"

> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal
>   characters. **To use a wildcard character as a literal character,
>   enclose the wildcard character in brackets.**

For example;

```
Symbol       -- Meaning
LIKE '[[]'   -- [
```

In your case, your your text should be `[[]CL` so,  you can use it as a string literal.

One solution can be replacing your `[` with `[[]` before you use it in `DataTable.Select` method like;

```
string s = txtSearchLog_Level.Text.Trim().Replace("[", "[[]");
DataRow[] searchResult = MyDataTable.Select("MYStps Like '%" + s + "%'");
```